# Can windbg preview edit memory data or register then save status with time travel debugging?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

windows release windbg preview with TTD(time trave debugging).

It's very brilliant. But I meet a problem.

When I set TTD, I can not edit register or memory data, like this

[image]

How can I edit register value, then save status and continue. So there are two status, one status is that register is changed, another is not changed.

I'm not familiar with TTD, so TTD can do this or has a function like this?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible.

TTD is basically a trace record of a program execution. Put simply it goes like this: for each instruction executed by the program, record (in a database) the state of all the registers, which memory address is accessed (if any) what is its value (and if a write happens what is the new value).

What you have at the end is the execution database, a trace of what your program did; you can interrogate the database, go wherever you want in it, even backward (which is why it is possible to "execute" something backward in TTD) but remember: the execution has already happened when you are using TTD, you are just 'browsing' through the execution database.

You are not allowed to change anything in the database, because doing so would impact the remaining of the program execution and, as the program execution has already been made, the debugger would have not mean to execute the new changes.

side note: there are some "debuggers" (more exactly proof of concept tools) that allows this kind of execution (record a trace, and then change the trace), in this case the execution is a mix between symbolic and what is called concolic execution. It is still an open problem in computer science as it leads quickly to combinatoric "explosion" due to all the cascading effects instructions generates.